# How this particular inequality deduced in finding the limit of a vector function?

Tags: differential-geometry, functions

There is a  proposition in differential geometry which states:

> Let $\vec{x}$ be a vector function from a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is defined over an interval containing $a$, through perhaps not at $a$ itself. Suppose in coordinates we have $\vec{x}(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ wherever $\vec{x}$ is defined. If $\vec{w} = (w_1, w_2)$, then $\lim_{t \to a} \vec{x}(t) = \vec{w}$ if and only if $\lim_{t \to a} x(t) = w_1$ and $\lim_{t \to a} y(t) = w_2$.

**Proof:**

Suppose first that $\lim_{t \to a}\vec{x}(t) = \vec{w}$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and let $\delta > 0$ satisfy the definition of the limit of the vector function. Note that $|x(t) - w_1| < ||\vec{x}(t) - \vec{w}||$ and $|y(t) - w_2| < ||\vec{x}(t) - \vec{w}||$ Hence, $0 < |t - a| < \delta$ implies $|x(t) - w_1| < \varepsilon$ and $|y(t) - w_2| < \varepsilon$ Thus, $\lim_{t \to a} x(t) = w_1$ and $\lim_{t \to a} y(t) = w_2$

---

**My Question:** How did the author of this theorem deduce that

$$
|x(t) - w_1| < ||\vec{x}(t) - \vec{w}|| \text{ and } |y(t) - w_2| < ||\vec{x}(t) - \vec{w}||
$$

Is it possible to help me find the answer why they are less than the other?

Comment: FYI, $\Vert$ is produced by \Vert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $||\vec{x}||$ is the square root of the sum of all its component squares. I think.

Answer (score 0):

For any vector $\vec x=(x_1,x_2)$, the Pythagorean Theorem tells you that $$\|\vec x\| =\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\,,$$ and so $|x_i|\le \|\vec x\|$.